# Detecting tab getting selected under jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to detect when a new tab on my jQueryui tab component is clicked.  I have followed several guides and blogs, but can't wrap my head around the process.  I have the following:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  select: function(event,ui) {
  alert('selected');
  return false;
  },                
});
```

I don't know what I'm missing, but the alert never fires. I'm am not strong with jQuery so I'm probably making a stupid mistake, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kris

Update: jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/T7czp/16/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you getting any errors? The trailing `,` after your `select` will break the script in some browsers.

This works as seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7czp/15/

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  select: function(event,ui) {
     alert('selected: '+ui.index);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have multiple events, so the comma is separating this and the next item.  When I break out this selector into it's own section it works fine, but not alongside the other events.  Is this normal, should I need to break each even into separate sections?

Comment: Could you update the snippet in your original question with these extra events, or perhaps put it into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can take a look at it?

Comment: While updating jsfiddle I noticed that the order of things doesn't seem right, but I can't identify what is wrong.  http://jsfiddle.net/T7czp/16/

Comment: Nice find.  Maybe I just spent too much time looking at the docs, but I thought that's where the select belonged.  Thanks for your clear and concise help!

Answer (score 5):

Latest version use

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  activate: function(event,ui) {
    alert('selected: '+ui.index);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

jquery UI seems to have changed slightly since the last accepted answer.

The ui parameter defined in teh activate function is now an object that looks similar to this:

Object { oldTab={...}, oldPanel={...}, newTab={...}, more...}

The index method is inside each of these. So the updated access method is:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  activate: function(event,ui) {
    alert('selected: '+ui.newTab.index());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the event to the tab.

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(e, tab) {
  alert("The tab at index " + tab.index + " was selected");
});
```

Comment: As with my other comment, this method also works great as it's own selector... but not when placed next to other events in the same selector.

Answer (score 1):

@Kristofer

You code is correct.

The only thing you must remove in order to the tab get selected  is the line:

```
return false;
```

because according with the [Tabs component documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs):

> Note that if a handler for the tabsselect event returns false, the clicked tab will not become selected (useful for example if switching to the next tab requires a form validation).

(the "tabselect" event corresponds to the "select" handler)